# Should I install an IKEA induction hob on single or three-phase power?

Tags: electrical, stove

I'm planing to buy an IKEA kitchen. We want to switch to electricity so we want to buy the FÖRDELAKTIG for a 60fm cabinet.

The diagram shows how to install with single-, two- or three-phase power but we don't really know what the difference is in terms of usage.

We had two electricians come in. One advised us to switch to a 3 phase meter (our at the moment is one phase) and the other say we probably don't need to and that two phases should be enough.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Will changing to a 3-phase meter affect (increase) your ongoing cost for power service (there will obviously be some cost involved in making the change.) If it will cost you more every month for the rest of your house's life, the *not upgrading the service option* looks more attractive, if it can be done. If it's only the one-time cost, 3 phase does have some advantages.

Comment: Note there are two manuals with different instructions.  See links in Answer from @ickybus.  If you can figure out *exactly* which cooker you are buying and  provide a link to its documentation that you are sure is correct, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an oversimplification, but if you have 3-phase power coming to your house, you have access to a higher line-line voltage than if you only have 1-phase or split-phase power.  However, all a higher voltage accomplishes for a range install is decreasing the amperage per phase, and letting you install it with a smaller wire.

You'll need to rely on local electricians for the specifics, but I would suspect it's highly unlikely that powering your stove would be enough reason to upgrade to 3-phase power, unless the total power of the stove is going to result in a panel upgrade anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I looked at [this other manual](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/manuals/foerdelaktig-induction-hob-integrated-extractor-ikea-500-black__AA-2310368-2-1.pdf)  on ikea.com! I will delete my other comment and my answer until I've read the new one and maybe understand why there are two manuals.  I'm still curious if the cooker actually uses phase-to-phase power at >220V. Not sure that can be determined from any of the docs.

Comment: For reference ickybus's [manual](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/manuals/foerdelaktig-induction-hob-integrated-extractor-ikea-700-black__AA-2312628-2-1.pdf) that he linked on my now-deleted answer.

Comment: Also interesting is that *your* manual does not document that power-limiting software function that allows the cooker to be installed on a 1-phase feed **less than** 7620W.    And it requires 4mm wire.   So with your manual, you unavoidably can consume 7620W on 4mm wire, which I believe in the UK would normally have a 32A breaker?  Is that correct?   I don't get it, unless an electrician would use a larger breaker, 6mm feeder and [a 4mm tail](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/285783/uk-ampacity-limits-for-appliance-power-cord-versus-house-wiring)?  Do you know?

Comment: I am not familiar with the UK regulations, nor the differences between the multiple versions of the cooktop.  I was just answering OP's question as asked in terms of ROI, assuming that they must have the three-phase version of the cooktop for it to even be a question.

Answer (score 1):

Running the cooker on three phases has the advantage of spreading the power usage across the three phases.  If you are at all close to your power limits at the moment, trying to run it all off one phase may trip a main breaker or fuse.

An electrician should be able to look at the loads on your supply at the moment, and work out how best to wire the cooker to minimise the chances of tripping anything.

The overall power used by the cooker will end up the same, however you wire it.

Answer (score 1):

The hob [takes max 7620W](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/manuals/foerdelaktig-induction-hob-integrated-extractor-ikea-700-black__AA-2312628-2-1.pdf).  If you have a single phase meter, the first question is whether your supply can handle this.  That depends on:

- The maximum supply current from your utility
- The rating of cables and switchgear in your house
- Any limitations on metering from your utility
- Other loads you have in your house

You didn't say your location, but electrical codes have ways to add up the existing loads to ensure that you don't exceed the supply.  Often it isn't as simple as adding up all the circuit breakers, because it's highly unlikely every single device will draw current at the same time (this is called 'diversity').  For example, this hob will only draw its maximum current if all the rings are turned up to maximum with pans of cold water on them, and the extractor running - this is very unlikely, and after a few minutes the pans will start boiling and the hob will reduce the load.

So first you need to know whether your supply can handle this load, on top of your existing installation.  Next is whether there will be extra costs incurred (in some countries you pay for a certain maximum current, and going to a higher current means a higher monthly fee, on top of the usage charges).

If your installation can handle it, and your metering is ok with it without costing extra, then there's not much reason to install three phase power, for extra cost.

If three phase brings other benefits, like lower monthly charges because the utility prefers you to use three phase, then maybe it is worth upgrading.

It all depends on what the charges and limitations are with your installation and your particular location/utility.